# To execute bash script from .bat file and .bat file is called by QT application

Tags: qt, bash, batch-file

I need help regarding executing bash script from batch scrip(.bat) which is called by Qt application inside Windows.

**Overview of  a problem:** I need to transfer files from Windows to Linux box via Qt application and run bash script inside linux to execute few commands.

**What I have done so far :**  I can successfully transfer the files from windows to Linux box via Qt application. The Qt application calls the batch file which transfers the file

example

```
 void Qt_intro101::on_file_upgrade_clicked()
 {
     QFileInfo fileInfo( ui->selected_file->text() );
     if( !fileInfo.exists() )
     {
         QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Information"),
                           tr("Unable to find file for upgrading!"));
        return;
     }

     // copying update
     QString fileName = fileInfo.absoluteFilePath();

      //Check if cmd.exe is present in Clients system and is located at correct path
      QFileInfo cmdFile( "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe");
      if( !cmdFile.exists() )
      {
          QMessageBox::information( this, tr( "Information" ),
                                  tr("Failed to find the cmd.exe ... Check cmd.exe is        installed and is in  C:\\Windows\\system32\\ !"));
           return;
      }

     QStringList arguments ;
     arguments << " /c" <<"c:\\temp\\upgradeTesting\\test.bat"<< fileName  ;
     QProcess *process = new QProcess( this );
     process->start( cmdFile.absoluteFilePath(), arguments ) ;
     if( !process->waitForStarted() )
     {
           QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Information"),
                             tr("Failed to start the process for upgrading!"));
           return;
      }


             QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Information"),
                             tr("Please wait while system is  upgrading   .. click Ok to exit this box"));
         qDebug() << fileName ;
         process->waitForFinished() ;
         qDebug() << process->readAllStandardOutput();
        QMessageBox::information( this, tr( "Information" ),
                             tr( "Upgradation is successful.. Please restart the system") ) ;
          process->deleteLater();

  }
```

---

I have writen a batch script(.bat) which executes command like

```
  pscp -pw "lol" "%TARGET_UPDATE%" squire@"%TARGET_IP%":"%BASE_DIR%"/
```

**For executing bash script via batch file  below is the command inside batch file**

```
  putty -pw "lol" -m test-update.sh squires@"%TARGET_IP%"
```

i have even tried something like that

```
  C:\\Program Files\\putty.exe -pw "lol"  -m test-update.sh squires@"%TARGET_IP%"
```

Could you guys please let me know where am i making mistake?

thanks and regards,
Sam

Answer (score 2):

I think it is easier to use QProcess::execute(QString cmdstring)
Than you can also pass arguments to the Batchfile itself

test.cpp

```
QFileInfo cmdFile( "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe");
QProcess *process = new QProcess( this );
process->execute(cmdFile.absoluteFilePath() + " /c helloparam.bat \"my param\"  ");
process->waitForFinished() ;
qDebug() << process->readAllStandardOutput();
```

helloparam.bat

```
@echo off
echo hello %1
```

Info: To test this in your IDE make shure that you are running your  application.exe from the release folder and have the batch file also in that folder

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `waitForStarted()` twice per run. If `waitForStarted()` returns false you're returning from method execution. So after `if( ! waitForStarted()` your process is running.

Comment: Yes You are right. I forget to change to change the code . I will ammend it now. but still it failed to run

Comment: After spending many hours , I realised i need to give full path name  in the batch script for Qt to execute it.   Without qt it works fine but if I want to run batch file  via QT app then I guess I need to give fully qualified path name of the bash script

Answer (score 0):

After spending many hours , I realised i need to give full path name  in the batch script for Qt to execute it.   Without qt it works fine but if I want to run batch file  via QT app then I guess I need to give fully qualified path name of the bash script. 
example

```
 putty.exe -pw "lol" -m C:\\temp\\upgradingTest\\test-update.sh squires@"%TARGET_IP%"
```

instead of

```
   putty -pw "lol" -m test-update.sh squires@"%TARGET_IP%"
```